# Apache + Nginx + HHVM FastCGI on Mac OS X not working?

Tags: nginx, php, mac-osx, fastcgi, hhvm

My `phpinfo()` correctly tells me that I am running HHVM 3.18.1 on my Apache webserver. If I try to load any PHP page other than my index.php, I get:

```
[Thu Aug 17 11:35:56.542841 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 19023] [client 127.0.0.1:59730] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header
[Thu Aug 17 11:35:56.543005 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 19023] (70014)End of file found: [client 127.0.0.1:59730] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : 
[Thu Aug 17 11:36:49.676178 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 19028] [client 127.0.0.1:59736] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header
[Thu Aug 17 11:36:49.676357 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 19028] (70014)End of file found: [client 127.0.0.1:59736] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
```

How do I fix this AH01067 / AH01075 error that conditionally triggers on some PHP pages?

Comment: Which web server is calling PHP? Please edit your question to clarify, and include the relevant configuration file. Also please untag the web server that's not relevant, you only need to tag the one that's got the PHP problem.

Comment: @Tim I thought that to get HHVM working with a redirect engine, I needed to install Nginx on top of Apache and then use Nginx's redirects instead of Apache's. Can I do redirects with just Apache + HHVM?

Comment: Nginx and Apache do pretty much the same thing. Also, I gave up on HHVM, I found it too buggy and unreliable - PHP7 is a better bet for most, though some of my old code only works on PHP5.6.

Comment: Yeah, my co-workers are migrating to Node.js but our current system is on PHP 5 and I'm looking to see if it can easily be upgraded to HHVM for a performance boost. We were getting bogged down on couple hundreds of thousands of requests which our system usually handles fine.

Comment: Try PHP7 first.